# Redux Tookit, How to dispatch action in a non component function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I have a global toast, which I am opening using redux slice. I need to open the toast for error message when call from api fails in api-slice of rtk-query.
I have seen the answer, using `store.dispatch` method, but this causes dependency cycle. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: adding some code snippet could help knowing the structure of your redux slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you should **always avoid directly importing the store into other application files**.

Ideally, none of the rest of your code would ever need to refer to `store` directly.

Depending on where in the RTKQ setup you need to trigger this toast, you *may* have access to `dispatch` as part of [the lifecycle function arguments](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#oncacheentryadded).

In the worst case, you can use [our fallback recommendation to inject the store into the necessary files from the app setup logic](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files).

Comment: While this does solve the problem, but in this way, I will have to do this for every endpoint which is repetitive. How I handled it was to create a custom middleware and listen for query fulfilled action. Then according to the payload received dispatch the toast action. This solution solves my problem but might not work for every use case.

Comment: Yep, that does sound like a good use for a custom middleware! You may also want to try using [our upcoming "action listener" middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/1648), which is meant to make it simple to write code that runs in response to specific actions. Should make this particular use case pretty simple to handle.  It's in alpha atm, but the API has mostly stabilized, and we'd like folks to try it and give us feedback.